# What causes text line break or disappearance when applying position absolute or fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position my footer responsively on my homepage but as soon as I apply position fixed or absolute, a line break appears in the text or half of it disappears and the spacing between elements within the footer changes.

What's causing this?

```
<div class="footer- callout">
</div>
<footer id="colophon" class="site- footer footer bg-dark" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container footer-inner">
      <div class="row">. 
         <div class="footer-widget-area">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-widget" role="complementary">
               <div id="text-60" class="widget widget_text">
                 <div class="textwidget">
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- .widget-area .first -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-widget" role="complementary"> 
              <div id="text-42" class="widget widget_text">
                 <div class="textwidget">
                    <div class="copyright">© 2020 4309.co.uk
                    </div>
                 <p><a  href="https://4309.co.uk/contact"><i class="fa fa-long arrow-right"></i>.</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Css:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {.page-id-28 #colophon {position: absolute; top: 400px;}}
```

Mobile page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: Please format your code. It's difficult to read. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: It's WordPress. Php generates the html as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Most of the time, absolutely positioned elements that have height and width set to auto are sized so as to fit their contents.

You need to set `width` of footer to `100%` or accordingly.

Also, you can achieve this by setting `left: 0` and `right: 0` no need to set width.